# How to show variables in trading view charts using text

Tags: pine-script

For debug purpose I would show in trading view chart some variable.
Every time I try to show a variable using pine I receive some kind of error , I tried using plot and label and other ways.

Suppose that I have this code

```
//@version=4
study("test", overlay=true)

    a = 20
    b = 2
    ob = 40
    os = -40
    // Range Calculation
    ll = lowest (low, a)
    hh = highest (high, a)
    diff = hh - ll
    rdiff = close - (hh+ll)/2
    avgrel = ema(ema(rdiff,b),b)
    avgdiff = ema(ema(diff,b),b)
    SMI = avgdiff != 0 ? (avgrel/(avgdiff/2)*100) : 0

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    SMIsignal = ema(SMI,b)
    emasignal = ema(SMI, 10)
```

Which is the code to show the SMIsignal and emasignal (using text) above each candle in my trading view chart ?

e.g. I tried

```
label.new(bar_index, high, text=emasignal)
```

but returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output a number, it must be converted to a string.

```
label.new(bar_index, high, text=tostring(emasignal))
```

Comment: Thank you ! But it works only for latest 50 candles. Is it possible to show for example latest 50 candles but starting 200 candles from current candle ?

Comment: `study("test", overlay=true, max_labels_count=200)`